# Link from one page to another to javascript show some content

Tags: javascript

I have the following script on a page that has a button to Show/Hide some content. I'd like to have a link from another page that would go to this page and open/show the content of one of the items. Is this possible to do?

Here's the onpage script and markup i'm using to to the Show/Hide;

Note: The '{trailitem:count}' is just an ExpressionEngine tag to add a unique number to each div. ExpressionEngine loops through and creates the divs with an incremental number, but the concept is the same so just imagine a series of divs with a unique ID.

```
<script>
function ToggleTrail{trailitem:count}() {
    var toggler = document.getElementById("trail_toggler{trailitem:count}");
    var first = document.getElementById("trail_first{trailitem:count}");
    var reveal = document.getElementById("trail_reveal{trailitem:count}");
    if(reveal.style.display != "block" && toggler.style.display != null) {
        toggler.style.display = "block";
        toggler.innerHTML = '» Hide';
        first.style.display = "block";
        reveal.style.display = "block";
    }else{
        toggler.style.display = "block";
        toggler.innerHTML = '» Reveal More';
        first.style.display = "block";
        reveal.style.display = "none";
    }
    return false;
}
</script>

<div class="trailbox">
    <a id="trail_toggler{trailitem:count}" class="button blackbutton viewallbutton" href="#" onclick="return ToggleTrail{trailitem:count}();">» Reveal More</a>
    <div id="trail_first{trailitem:count}">

        First content

    </div>

    <div id="trail_reveal{trailitem:count}">

        Content to be revealed

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That's right. The way it works is a page has a number of related pieces of content and the count just literally sees how many pieces of related content there are and assigns a number.

Comment: I could probably modify it a bit to grab part of the url and use that as a unique id instead of a number. I can easily get this on both pages.